# How to set footer responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two pages, in one of them I can put the rodabe below with:

```
 #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

However, on the second page I have a Bootstrap dataTable and can choose how many columns show on the page, if I leave the footer absolute table data pass through the footer, causing me to alter the CSS:

```
 #footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

But with this second CSS on my first page, the footer appears in the middle of the screen.
I want the both pages stay always at the bottom of the screen and get the recursion when the screen is increasing as the datatable .

How can I do that?

Comment: google sticky footer

Comment: Using sticky footer is the same as position: absolute.

Comment: Could you show a working example of what you have?

Comment: its not the same http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/9unq0d8h/

Comment: @btevfik http://imgur.com/nKPWypv it is.

Comment: @Zentaurus If I use absolute my page looks like this: http://imgur.com/35OqjhN that bar with the year is my footer. If i use relative in this case that work. But i use relative my other page stay like that: http://imgur.com/5i9W1Eo . I want the both!

Comment: It's some type of sticky footer you need, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicaly you just set the CSS

```
html, body {height:100%;}

.geral {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

The technique is to say that the html will occupy 100% of the page.

View the complete explanation in [this link](http://tableless.com.br/colocar-rodape-fixo-no-bottom/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bootstrap, why not just add the .navbar-fixed-bottom class to the footer. Like this: http://www.bootply.com/aCRnwLXMwN

```
<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background:#999;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Without something to look at in JsFiddle, Codepen, or something like that, I was really just guessing as to what you were specifically talking about. It wasn't really all that clear. But I am glad your problem is resolved.

Comment: I appears you did not examine the link I provided and do not understand the use of the navbar-fixed-bottom class. What I proposed does not make anything appear in the navbar. This actually does make the element appear fixed to the bottom, like you wanted. So you were actually incorrect in your assessment and examination of my solution.

Comment: Yeah!! Thx, i dont use ur solution for this case, but i use in other, my problem was for make one rodape fixed and relative, was having problem with CSS.

Comment: The .navbar-fixed-bottom class adds the same style rules to the element that it's applied to as what is contained in the solution above. Go see for yourself in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom).